# Getting angular templating routing isn't working, but showing no errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-template

I am completely new to angular templating, and I am trying to routing to work in my webpage. So I want to be able to navigate to different html pages without refreshing the page. I followed the steps on w3schools, however it doesn't seem to be working. This is the code below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/borrower", {
    templateUrl : "../borrower.html"
})
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "administrator.html"
})
.when("/book", {
    templateUrl : "../book.html"
})
.when("/author", {
    templateUrl : "../author.html"
})
.when("/publisher", {
    templateUrl : "../publisher.html"
})
.when("/loans", {
    templateUrl : "../loans.html"
});
});

<ol class="menunav"><a href="#/!"><span class="menu-text">Administrator</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!borrower"><span class="menu-text">Borrowers</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!book"><span class="menu-text">Books</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!author"><span class="menu-text">Authors</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!publisher"><span class="menu-text">Publishers</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!loans"><span class="menu-text">Loans</span></a></ol>
```

I have added    ng-app="myApp" to the body tag at the top and I have added the libraries needed I am not getting any errors. I am on the administrator.html page, and I have added the above code to this file. But I am not able to get to the other pages by using the angular code above. As I said I am brand new to this so it might be an obvious fix, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciate, thanks

Comment: Might it have something to do with the pathing? All except adminstrator.html are in '../*'?

Comment: @KristjánJóel i took out the ../ but it still isnt working. i am getting this at the end of my url /administrator.html#!/borrower

Comment: Do you have <base href="#!" /> or something similar in your main html file? If not try that

Comment: @KristjánJóel I have this <a href="#/!">

Comment: I assume that is the link to the administrator page, however you want <base href="#!" /> inside the <head></head> in your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index.html with the code you have posted.

In this file you also need a base tag and set the ng-view.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Example:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>myApp</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/borrower", {
            templateUrl : "../borrower.html"
        })
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "administrator.html"
        })
        .when("/book", {
            templateUrl : "../book.html"
        })
        .when("/author", {
            templateUrl : "../author.html"
        })
        .when("/publisher", {
            templateUrl : "../publisher.html"
        })
        .when("/loans", {
            templateUrl : "../loans.html"
        });
    });
</script>
<base href="/">
</head>
<body xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#/!"><span class="menu-text">Administrator</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!borrower"><span class="menu-text">Borrowers</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!book"><span class="menu-text">Books</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!author"><span class="menu-text">Authors</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!publisher"><span class="menu-text">Publishers</span></a></ol>
        <ol class="menunav"><a href="#!loans"><span class="menu-text">Loans</span></a></ol>
        <div class="templateLoadsHere" data-ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh right ok, so I have all the links as well as index.html, and then index would be <a href="#/!"> ?

Comment: @CD6554 No, you would have your server setup to have index.html as the default so when you visit https://www.yoursite.com/ it will load index.html and angularjs will load administrator.html into the data-ng-view div

Comment: @CD6554 oh and you'll likely need your base tag to be <base href="#!" /> not <base href="/" />

Comment: So in replace of "<div class="templateLoadsHere" "what do I add? Ok thanks, will change the base href now

Comment: @CD6554 nothing you just need <div data-ng-view></div> and your route (template html) will be placed into that automatically

Comment: Using this code just crashes the page. It wont let me click on anything